# unable to run my nfc application

Tags: android, nfc

I m creating a sample Nfc application.. in GingerBread2.3.3 - which includes nfc features.. i have checked for the Nfc service running on the system bootup... the service runs perfectly on boot up...

I m using an external hardware to detect the Nfc tags... the hardware is fine... checked it also...

From my application, i have set permission for Nfc and I have included the Nfc feature also..

I found out that NfcAdapter.java - hasSystemFeature() is returning false for Nfc... but my Nfc service is running.... In settings, I don't get any Nfc related features..  On setting this hasSystemFeature() to return true. I get the Nfc settings. But my application does nothing..

I checked in current.xml whether it includes nfc features.. and it also has Nfc features..

Now I m struck not sure what to do.. Pls do help me out with this...

Comment: Which phone are you using?  Is it a Nexus S?

Comment: @Indhu can u tell which hardware are you using?